# Testing REST/JSON input media, IBM i Integrated Web Services (IWS) receiving err "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request "

Tags: json, rest

I am getting error using IBM's Integrated Web Services (IWS) on the IBM i (a.k.a AS400) w/RPG and getting this message, when trying to test a RESTful web service to accept JSON as input media. When input media is ALL it works, but trying to use POST with input media JSON. BTW - I am new to all of this web stuff. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request 
Date: Mon, 01 May 2017 14:19:41 GMT 
Server: Apache 
X-Powered-By: IBM i 
Content-Length: 119 
Connection: close 
Content-Type: text/plain

com.ibm.as400.access.ExtendedIllegalArgumentException: javaValue ({ "pinname": "Cecil Jones" } 
): Length is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

When input media is ALL it works, because Content-Type: text/plain is accepted. 
If you want deploy service as json service you should in request headers specify: 
Content-Type : application/json